# Cannot install ruby using gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I am trying to configure chef on an RHEL6 box.
When I execute command **rvm use 1.9.3@chef**  I get the following message **ruby-1.9.3-p551 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551'**

Now when I try to follow the above instructions to install ruby I get the following error:

```
`requirements_centos_libs_install`     

    requirements_centos_libs_install ()      

    {      
        __rvm_try_sudo yum install -y "$@" || return $?  
    }  

    current path: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551  

    GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551  

    PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/bin  
    GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global  
    command(9): requirements_centos_libs_install autoconf gcc-c++ readline-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel automake libtool bison  
    ++ __rvm_try_sudo yum install -y autoconf gcc-c++ readline-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel automake libtool bison  
    ++ typeset -a command_to_run  
    ++ typeset sudo_path sbin_path missing_paths  
    ++ command_to_run=("$@")  
    ++ ((  UID == 0  ))  
    ++ yum install -y autoconf gcc-c++ readline-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel automake libtool bison  
    Loaded plugins: security  
    Setting up Install Process  
    No package autoconf available.  
    No package gcc-c++ available.  
    No package readline-devel available.  
    No package zlib-devel available.  
    No package openssl-devel available.  
    No package automake available.  
    No package libtool available.  
    No package bison available.  
    Error: Nothing to do  
    ++ return 1  
    ++ return 1  
    ~
```

Can someone help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Is Yum set up correctly? It seems it can't resolve the packages from the yum repo. What does `yum list autoconf` return?

Comment: use "rvm requirements" to check ruby requirements.

Comment: @Novae-Thanks it got resolved. There was an issue with the yum configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that the correct way to install Chef is using the official omnibus packages. These are self-contained and so ship their own Ruby environment, making rvm unnecessary.